# set default fonts, shapes, etc in powerpoint through registry, not themes

Tags: powerpoint

I apologize, this may sound like it has been asked before, but the answers I found do not seem to work in my case.

Is there a way to set the default powerpoint options (fonts, shapes, colors, fills, thicknesses etc) in the *registry options*, rather than jumping through hoops (saving a default theme via Slidemaster, which is the current way suggested my MS). I find that each time I manage to set my own default theme to propagate across all newly created PPTX files, Microsoft finds a way to enforce its default themes. The current recommended method of creating a default theme through SlideMaster only seems to work when I do file_new_custom theme, and set that as a default. But it does not seem to work for 'blank presentation', and for creating a new file with *pptx extension outside of PowerPoint. Actually, I would much prefer if the entire theme selection window never appeared, all I need is a blank white screen, with the settings I know and like.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> > Is there a way to set the default powerpoint options (fonts, shapes, colors, fills, thicknesses etc) in the registry option

No. These are all "presentation-level" defaults, not "application-level". They travel with and can be different for each PPTX file or template/theme file.

What you *can* do is create your own default presentation, the one you get when you choose new blank presentation. I've got an article about this on the PPT FAQ site I maintain:

Create a default "blank" presentation with your own defaults
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00245_Create_a_default_-blank-_presentation_with_your_own_defaults.htm

You'll also want to read this:

Set default text and drawing shape styles
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00039_Set_default_text_and_drawing_shape_styles.htm

If that still leaves questions, post back (and please indicate the version of Office you have ... e.g. Windows Office 365 or whatever ... platform and version.  It matters.)

Comment: Thank you, Steve,

I have tried the 'Blank' template, and I just did it again with a fresh 2018 Office, following the instructions on your page. It worked for the scenario when one creates a PPTX file by starting powerpoint first, then file>new. It did not work, however, when, instead of starting powerpoint, I created a new file by rightclick>create new powerpoint presentation in a folder, and then double-clicked the new pptx file. Upon the first launch of the new file, powerpoint pullEd out its default ghastly settings. Perhaps, there is yet another template to edit to address that scenario

Comment: Found the exact same question on the microsoft discussion board. In this user's case, he, apparently, found a workaround by making .pptx files not display upon right-click>new. This is not what I was looking for, however. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_winother-mso_2016/how-to-use-an-existing-powerpoint-file-as-default/d5da050d-993e-478e-aa7a-c02ce416a7de